# How do I Import a CSV file to google voice with different fields than a normal contact?

Tags: google-voice

1. I want to import bulk phone numbers, addresses, and business names to google voice.
2. The CSV file I am trying to import has different fields than a normal contact field and the system won't process the file.
3. I have tried adding the fields from my CSV file, but that only works for one specific contact.

Thanks so much!